# How to run IIS7 Application Pool under domain account?

Tags: security, iis-7, msmq

What are the steps to be made to run an IIS7 Application Pool under a domain account? I know how to create a domain account and how to set the identity of the Application Pool.

My question is rather what rights does this Domain Account need to have? (logon right to the server? read rights to the files of the web sites running under application pool?)

The reason I want to run the Application Pool under a domain account is to set security on a remote MSMQ queue.